# Get secret name by value from azure Key vault

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-keyvault, key-value-store

The idea is that user send me an api-key and I return him a name of his brand. The api key it's a GUID so I can't store it as a secret name.

I am looking for a way to **retrieve a secret name by value from a keyvault**. That's what my team came up with but it very slow and dramatically increases when adding new secrets to key vault.

```
public String getClientApiKeyName(final String apiKeyValue) {
        for (SecretProperties secretProperties : secretClient.listPropertiesOfSecrets()) {
            if (secretProperties.isEnabled()) {
                final KeyVaultSecret secretWithValue = secretClient.getSecret(
                        secretProperties.getName(),
                        secretProperties.getVersion()
                );
                if (secretWithValue.getValue().equals(apiKeyValue)) {
                    return secretWithValue.getName();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: As Ken W MSFT said, you shouldnt use Key Vault for this case. I would use a simple storage table with key and the brand and restrict the storage accordingly. 

This also has the advantage that you can add more properties later if necessary without any problems. A key vault simply restricts you too much. And the problem of performance is also eliminated. 


From a security point of view, you should not use the storage master key. If you also host your app in Azure, then it is best to use a managed identity.

Answer (score 1):

Key Vault is designed for your own services secrets. If you are storing your customers' secrets (especially for high-throughput key storage scenarios), consider putting the keys in a database or storage account with encryption, and storing just the master key in Azure Key Vault.

### Throttling

If you are seeing error code 429, you should the following are **best practices** you should implement:

- Reduce the number of operations per request.
- Reduce the frequency of requests.
- Avoid immediate retries.

  - All requests accrue against your usage limits.

#### Backoff code example

```
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
         }
    };
    var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://keyVaultName.vault.azure.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential(),options);
                                 
    //Retrieve Secret
    secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-throttling

Comment: I'm confused - why did you put information about throttling in this response?  I don't see it in the original question.

Comment: The question says "slow and dramatically increases when adding new secrets to key vault".  This could be bc they are hitting the service limits.  While the poster didn't say they were getting 429's I thought it was worthwhile to show how to properly request keys from KV at scale.